# How does an Eulerian path have vertices with odd degree?

Tags: graph-theory

Shouldn't a Eulerian path have vertices having only an even degree of paths? One leading in and one leading out? 
How can a vertex with three paths (odd degree) become a part of Eulerian path since you would have to cross the vertex twice to follow all three paths?

Comment: What about the graph $P_2$ with two vertices and one edge?

Comment: Note the difference between an Eulerian path (or trail) and an Eulerian circuit.  The existence of the latter surely requires all vertices to have even degree, but the former only requires that all but 2 vertices have even degree, namely: the ends of the path may have odd degree.

Comment: An Eulerian path visits each edge exactly once. A Hamiltonian path visits each vertex exactly once.

Answer (score 4):

An Eulerian path need not be a circuit. If it’s not a circuit, it has two endpoints, and they must have odd degree. In the case of the graph shown below, the endpoint labelled $F$ has degree $3$, while that labelled $S$ has degree $1$:

```
                      S    F
                      o----o----o  
                           |    |  
                           o----o
```